# How to delete all documents from mongoDB using deleteMany()?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, http, axios, http-delete

I am trying to use Express + MongoDB building React app.

I was able to successfully post some documents to MongoDB using POST method but I cannot figure out how to delete all the documents using DELETE (I am trying to have a single document in the DB instead of a list of them).

These are my routes:

```
router.post('/totalbalance', (request, response) => {
    const totalBalance = new TotalBalanceModelTemplate({
        totalBalance:request.body.totalBalance,
    });
    totalBalance.save()
    .then(data => {
        response.json(data);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        response.json(error);
    });
});

router.delete('/totalbalance', (request, response) => {
    request.body.totalBalance.deleteMany({}, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            response.status(500).send({error: "Could not clead database..."});           
        } else {
            response.status(200).send({message: "All info was deleted succesfully..."});
        }
    });
});
```

These are axios request:

```
axios.post('http://localhost:4000/app/totalbalance', 
 {
        totalBalance: newTotalBalance
 });

useEffect(() => {
    axios.delete('http://localhost:4000/app/totalbalance')
        .then(res => {
            console.log('request here ', res);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        })
}, []);
```

When I launch the app, in the Chrome console I see error "xhr.js:177 DELETE http://localhost:4000/app/totalbalance 500 (Internal Server Error)" (it is because i use useEffect() passing an empty array as the dependency, so it is run once after the initial rendering of React component).

How should DELETE be done?
Maybe I should combine POST and DELETE methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the `deleteMany` function on the Mongoose model. `request.body.totalBalance` would not be a model.

It looks like you need the `.delete` route to be the following.

```
router.delete('/totalbalance', (request, response) => {
    TotalBalanceModelTemplate.deleteMany({}, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            response.status(500).send({error: "Could not clead database..."});           
        } else {
            response.status(200).send({message: "All info was deleted succesfully..."});
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: @grubbyGerbil - Awesome. Happy to help. Good luck on your coding journey!